# Tomcat - HSQLDB

Tags: jsp, tomcat, hsqldb

I'm working with `Tomcat`, I want to get an attribute from my HSQLDB database and accents are replaced by characters like **"Ã ©"**.

My JSP contains

`<"html text /; charset = UTF-8"% @ page contentType =%>` tag and my database inserts are made with PreparedStatement with **setString** etc.

How to have accents in my view?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

HSQLDB uses UTF-16 to store and retrieve data. You need to tell JSP how to convert the data to UTF-8.

I haven't used JSP for a long time, but I think the `<html>` tag should be separate.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType = "text/html ; charset= UTF-8" %>
<html>

</html>
```

Comment: I have already put this in my JSP :-\ accents are OK from JSP but not from hsqldb queries